PostgreSQL / PostGIS - trouble implementing triggers to insert geometries
Testing environment: PostgreSQL 16/PostGIS running on Windows10
Production environment : PostgreSQL 16/PostGIS running on Ubuntu server 24.04
Two tables involved a well_parent table:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.well_parent
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('well_parent_id_seq'::regclass),
    well_no character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    easting numeric(14,6),
    northing numeric(14,6),
    purpose character varying(25) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    country character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    admin1 character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    admin2 character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    admin3 character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    settlement character varying(250) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    orig_wellno character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    date_completed date NOT NULL,
    elev numeric(6,2),
    status boolean,
    geom geometry(Point,4326),
    coord_sys integer,
    created timestamp without time zone DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,


This table has a trigger that converts the text input of coordinates on a form into binary geometry objects. The trigger and associated functions are as follows:
TRIGGER FUNCTION
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_make_pointgeom()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    IF  new.coord_sys = 4326 
THEN
        new.geom = ST_Point(new.easting::float, new.northing::float, 4326);
    ELSE 
        new.geom = ST_Transform(ST_Point(new.easting::float, new.northing::float, new.coord_sys), 4326); 
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$;
COMMENT ON FUNCTION public.fn_make_pointgeom()
    IS 'to convert text input into binary geometry objects';


called by this trigger:
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_make_pointgeom
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE 
    ON public.well_parent
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION public.fn_make_pointgeom();


Both the trigger and the function work as expected in the test environment. Porting the trigger and its function into the production environment resulted in the same success, in both the cases of record-by-record entry via a php form, and bulk data import through the COPY command. So far, so good.
I created another table, a child table which is actually a subset of the well parent table in that it holds data totally derived from the well_parent table – but only wells whose purpose= ‘monitoring’. However, easting and northing are switched and formulated as lat and long, and mw_id is actually the orig_wellno in the well_parent table, and location holds the same values as settlement:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.monitoring_wells
(
    mw_id character varying(12) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    location character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    lat numeric(14,6),
    "long" numeric(14,6),
    elev numeric(6,2),
    geom geometry,
    well_no character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
)

Although it could be argued that it is possible to produce this table as a virtual table through a VIEW, I did not choose this approach because I require a persistent database object for reasons slightly off-topic. However, to ensure consistency, I needed a trigger to automate the filling in of data for wells whose purpose = ‘monitoring’ Thus this trigger and associated function:
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_monitoring_well_insert
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE 
    ON public.well_parent
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION public.fn_monitoring_well_insert();

COMMENT ON TRIGGER tr_monitoring_well_insert ON public.well_parent
    IS 'Execute function to place new wells into monitoring wells table from data in well-parent ';

--**TRIGGER FUNCTION**

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_monitoring_well_insert()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
begin
--perform pg_sleep(1);
    insert into monitoring_wells (mw_id, location, lat, long, elev, geom, well_no )
select new.orig_wellno, new.settlement,
new.northing,new.easting, new.elev, new.geom,  
new.well_no --from well_parent
where new.purpose='monitoring'
and created = current_timestamp;

-- THIS COMMENT EXPLAINED LATER - extract(minutes from created)= extract(minutes from localtimestamp);

return new ;

end;
$BODY$;

This also works in the testing environment. But in the production environment,  it was able to insert all the values EXCEPT FOR THE GEOMETRY COLUMN.
Triggers are fired in alphabetical order, so the sequence is not a problem.
Thinking somehow that on the server, there could be a delay, perhaps, in the first trigger converting the geometry, that makes the timestamp when the record is inserted (the ‘created’ field) older than the current_timestamp.
I made the following modification
“and created = extract(minutes from created)= extract(minutes from localtimestamp);”
I also used pg_sleep, but that didn't help either.
Note this is the commented out line in the code above. This did not affect the outcome.
But I don’t think this is the problem, because not only does this trigger fail, but now the first trigger also fails, notably the ST_POINT function for converting the text input into binary geometry objects. So geometry is not inserted into the monitoring wells table because IT WAS NEVER CREATED DURING THE FIRST TRIGGER!
Even after removing the second trigger, this behavior persists – in other words the ST_POINT function in the first trigger - fn_make_pointgeom() - doesn’t work. Meanwhile, both triggers work fine in the testing environment.
What I did then was to put a raise notice 'trigger fired' into the code, then issued an insert statement outside the php form in order to see the message in pgAdmin,
NOTICE:  trigger fired
INSERT 0 1

Query returned successfully in 371 msec.

Still the geometry column is null, even though the trigger fired. I am baffled, as the code is clean, and worked once before without problems, the very same code. What could be causing this behavior?

An AFTER trigger can‘t modify the inserted row. CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_make_pointgeom AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE …

Change it to BEFORE

@clamp -YES that was the problem. What confused me is that on the test db, I had the trigger firing BEFORE, that's why it worked but on the production db for some reason that I can't remember, I changed it to AFTER.

Thanks goes to clamp who saw the problem right away. The first trigger that creates the geometry must fire before insert or update actions. . What confused me is that on the test db, I had the trigger firing BEFORE, that's why it worked but on the production db for some reason that I can't remember, I changed it to AFTER.
